# access usb with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a bash script that tries to access a usb directory, but it cant find it, I tried running "ls /media/username/" it returns nothing, but when I run the exact same command in my terminal it returns the usb directory, the script also works when I run it manually. The script is triggerd with a udevd trigger. Could i mayby run the script as a user with the udevd, would that help?

If you have any questions please comment them I will answer them ass quickly as I can.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: which trigger specifically? Maybe it's triggered just before the device is mounted?

Comment: 99-usb-trigger something, and i have tried using sleep 5 in the start of my script

Comment: can you actually post your udev trigger in your question? this seems important, at least to me

Comment: Yes of course, SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/wifiScript.sh'"

Comment: can you really put the *full* udev trigger **in your question text**, using code formatting?As it looks now, this script 1. runs anytime *any* block device is added, which seems undesirable, and 2. runs before the block device is mounted, which means you can't access the contents of the (not yet mounted) filesystem.

Comment: Im sorry, im pretty new to linux, how do i get the full udev trigger, and yes the trigger will get triggered by any block device, thats what i want to happen, if there is a more secure way of doing that let me know. Does the usb get mounted after the process is killed/done, in that case, cant I just have my bash script run another script that waits for 5 seconds so the udev trigger event can stop? And thanks for helping me

Comment: the file that you copied the text from that you pasted in the command above, take that whole file, and copy and paste it into your question instead of into a comment, please :) Afterwards, select the text you just pasted, and click on the code formatting button, which is labeled `{}` above the text entry field. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah okay, ill do that now!

Comment: Re: modify your script to wait after the block device appeared: don't! You'd be solving a problem you only have by having chosen the wrong trigger. Instead of triggering on every block device, trigger on a mount / mount change!

Comment: Yeah okay, that sounds better tbh, and with the file, i cant really get access to it, it's on my raspberry pi and im using SSH from a windows computer, I tried using SCP but didnt succed, but what kind of information would you want from that, i maybe could get it for you? Im really sorry for making everything harder :/

Comment: you can SSH into your Rpi, and `cat /path/to/file` and then copy and paste that text.